# crop picture in the middle with javascript

Tags: javascript

my image is 800 x 600px, I need to crop this pic in the midlle (600 x 600px)

I create this code but is not working

```
function takeSnapshot(){
    // Here we're using a trick that involves a hidden canvas element.  

    var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
        context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');


        // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
        context.drawImage(video, 100, 0, 600, 600);
        // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
        return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
   
}
```

---

this is my full code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // References to all the element we will need.
    var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),
        image = document.querySelector('#snap'),
        start_camera = document.querySelector('#start-camera'),
        controls = document.querySelector('.controls'),
        take_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#take-photo'),
        delete_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#delete-photo'),
        download_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#download-photo'),
        error_message = document.querySelector('#error-message');


    // The getUserMedia interface is used for handling camera input.
    // Some browsers need a prefix so here we're covering all the options
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);


    if(!navigator.getMedia){
        displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
    }
    else{

        // Request the camera.
        navigator.getMedia(
            {
                video: true
            },
            // Success Callback
            function(stream){

                // Create an object URL for the video stream and
                // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
                video.srcObject=stream;
                // Play the video element to start the stream.
                video.play();
                video.onplay = function() {
                    showVideo();
                };
         
            },
            // Error Callback
            function(err){
                displayErrorMessage("There was an error with accessing the camera stream: " + err.name, err);
            }
        );

    }



    // Mobile browsers cannot play video without user input,
    // so here we're using a button to start it manually.
    start_camera.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // Start video playback manually.
        video.play();
        showVideo();

    });


    take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var snap = takeSnapshot();

        // Show image. 
        image.setAttribute('src', snap);
        image.classList.add("visible");

        // Enable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");

        // Set the href attribute of the download button to the snap url.
        download_photo_btn.href = snap;

        // Pause video playback of stream.
        video.pause();

    });


    delete_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // Hide image.
        image.setAttribute('src', "");
        image.classList.remove("visible");

        // Disable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");

        // Resume playback of stream.
        video.play();

    });


  
    function showVideo(){
        // Display the video stream and the controls.

        hideUI();
        video.classList.add("visible");
        controls.classList.add("visible");
    }


    function takeSnapshot(){
        // Here we're using a trick that involves a hidden canvas element.  

        var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
            context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');


            // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
            context.drawImage(video, 100, 0, 600, 600);
            // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
            return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
       
    }


    function displayErrorMessage(error_msg, error){
        error = error || "";
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        }

        error_message.innerText = error_msg;

        hideUI();
        error_message.classList.add("visible");
    }

   
    function hideUI(){
        // Helper function for clearing the app UI.

        controls.classList.remove("visible");
        start_camera.classList.remove("visible");
        video.classList.remove("visible");
        snap.classList.remove("visible");
        error_message.classList.remove("visible");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

To crop try...

```
 var imgData = context.getImageData(100, 0, 600, 600); // start from 100px and a width of 600px

 context.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0); // or place it back at X=100px, its up to you.
```

Btw, your URL returned should be...

For PNG:

```
 URL=hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('image/png','image/octet-stream');
```

For JPG:

```
 URL=hidden_canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't change anything manu, cropping is simple...

```
var Data=context.getImageData(100, 0, canvas.width-100,canvas.height); // grab the portion you want

context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear the old image so the crop shows better

context.putImageData(Data,0,0); // paste it in
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

```
let data = context.getImageData(100, 0, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height); 

context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

context.putImageData(data, 0, 0);
```